# The error message indicates that there is an issue with the import statement from object_detection.utils

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

```
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format
```

The error message indicates that there is an issue with the import statement from object_detection.utils. Specifically, it looks like there is a problem with the import of eval_pb2 from object_detection.protos. What can I do for it. I am using tensorflow 2. This is a part of the error msg I got,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)der_pb

   (...)

TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

I tried to Update Config For Transfer Learning. When I Downgrade the protobuf package it said that it is not compatible with tf2.